# Android 2D image array

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, 2d

I'm taking on a simple game as my first android project. It uses 'tile' graphics from maybe 5 different images in the drawables (one for walls, one for doors, etc.) with the images tiled 8 vertically by 15 across. This takes a lot of coding to set up 120 separate imageView's, so I've been looking for an array-type solution (preferably 2d). If anyone has experience creating a 2d array of imageviews, I'd appreciate some advice or a pointer towards some literature to get me started, as I haven't found anything helpful yet.

Thanks, and happy coding
Spencer D

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what the question is here. Are you wanting just the code to create an array of image views?
If so, I put my answer below.

Comment: code would be great, but a link to more information on the topic would be even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ImageView[] arrayOfImageViews= new ImageView[size];

More on how to use the array once you have made it can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html